# Scrapy spider not following pagination

Tags: scrapy

I am using code from this link(https://github.com/eloyz/reddit/blob/master/reddit/spiders/pic.py) but somehow I am unable to visit paginated page.

I am on using scrapy 1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any mechanism for processing next page, all you do is gathering images.

Here is what you should be doing, I wrote some selectors but didn't test it.

from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy import Request
import urlparse

class xxx_spider(Spider):
    name = "xxx"
    allowed_domains = ["xxx.com"]

```
def start_requests(self):
    url = 'first page url'
    yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, meta={"page":1})


def parse(self, response):
    page = response.meta["page"] + 1
    html = Selector(response)

    pics = html.css('div.thing')
    for selector in pics:                
        item = PicItem()
        item['image_urls'] = selector.xpath('a/@href').extract()
        item['title'] = selector.xpath('div/p/a/text()').extract()
        item['url'] = selector.xpath('a/@href').extract()

        yield item

    next_link = html.css("span.next-button a::attr(href)")
    if not next_link is None:
        yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, meta={"page":page})
```

Similar to what you did, but when I get images, I then check next page link, if it exists then I yield another request with it.

Mehmet